# I’m having trouble getting a motor to run for 10 seconds and then reverse direction every time push button is pushed down

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, l293d

i am brand new to arduino and was looking for a little help. i am looking to activate a motor once the button is pushed for 10 seconds and then have it stop. then the next time the button is pushed, it runs in reverse for ten seconds and stops. i need it to continue this cycle everytime the button is pushed. button push 1 = forward 10 seconds, button push 2 = reverse ten seconds, button push 3 = forward 10 seconds and so on... i believe i am very close to accomplishing this task however like i said i am new to all this and i could be miles away. any help would be appreciated. i am using a mega 2560 even though the picture shows an UNO. i dont think itll matter as long as i use the correct pins.
[link to tinkercad.com](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/87HCwRBbweN-stunning-esboo-hillar/editel?sharecode=wSmZURvHPVNHDUkKud8zMDtZFs6znFj78JnjbHiDQpM)

```
int BUTTON = 9;
int DIRA = 3;
int DIRB = 4;
int FOR = true; //forward - reverse 
int ENABLE = 5;

 
void setup() {
  //---set pin direction
  pinMode (ENABLE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DIRA,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIRB,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == HIGH) {
   digitalWrite(ENABLE, HIGH);
   if (FOR == true) {
    digitalWrite(DIRA,HIGH); //on forward
    digitalWrite(DIRB,LOW);
    delay(10000);
    FOR = false;
    digitalWrite(ENABLE,LOW);  //stop
   } else {
    digitalWrite(DIRB,HIGH); //on reverse
    digitalWrite(DIRA,LOW);
    delay(1000);
    FOR = true;
    digitalWrite(ENABLE,LOW); //stop
  }  
 }  
}`
```

[image]

Comment: you did not fully describe the desired behavior ... what should happen if the button is pressed and held? .... what about pressed, released and pressed again after one second?

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? Does it behave differently than expected? Then please describe in detail what you expected and what actually happened.

Comment: thanks for the replies. i hadnt even thought about different types of button presses. what i would like is that no matter if the button is pressed once, pressed and held, or pressed multipliple times, id like it to complete its cycle before the button can be pressed again. so on the push down it starts the cycle, and doesnt stop until the cycle is complete.

nothing happens when i push the button with my code and circuit as is.

Comment: the description of the problem belongs in the question at top of this page ... this site is not a forum ... reduce your code to only a push button that lights an LED when pressed ... does that work as expected?

Comment: Yes I I can get the push button to work without the motor controlling a simple RGB LED

Comment: next, write very simple code to test the motor ... run one direction for 2 seconds. stop for 2 seconds, run in other direction for 2 seconds, stop

Comment: Yes I did that already, I was able to get it to work without the L293D chip but can’t seem to get it to work with it

Comment: If you bypass the Arduino and just connect the motor wires to +5V & GND, does the motor spin? Can you get the motor to go in reverse by switching the wires?  If you can verify that then the next step would be to bypass the Arduino and  just use manual jumper wires to provide the correct voltages to the driver chip.  If this works, then you have eliminated everything except your code (assuming no dead Arduino pins).  Then replace the motor and driver chip with a simple resistor-LED combination on your output pins to provide a visual indication for output pin activity.